# If $f'$ is defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$, can we conclude that $f'$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

A read a comment by a reputable user that gave me pause. The claim implied that if $f'$ is defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$, we cannot conclude that $f'$ is bounded. Taking this argument in the context of $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, I feel like this claim is incorrect, but maybe I am misunderstanding something.

It is certainly true that just because $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ does not mean that $f$ is bounded. A good example disproving this is the function: $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} \quad& x\neq 0\\c \quad&x=0\end{cases}$ (for simplicitly of my argument later on, let $c \geq 0$).

However, from my understanding of Darboux's Theorem, such a function would not be eligible for consideration in the context of a derivative. Why?

Darboux's theorem states that if $f'$ is defined on $[a,b]$, then if $f'(a) \lt \alpha \lt f'(b)$, there exists a $z \in(a,b): f'(z)=\alpha$. **IF** we had the following function: $f'(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} \quad& x\neq 0\\c \quad&x=0\end{cases}$, then this violates Darboux because I can set $a=0$ and $b={\frac{1}{c+1}}$ and let $\alpha \in (c,c+1)$. As such, no $z$ exists $\in (0,\frac{1}{c+1})$ that will result in $f'(z)=\alpha$.

Are there other functions that get around this? Maybe there is an exotic function that I am not properly taking into consideration.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2 \sin{\left ( \frac{1}{x^2} \right )}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x=0$. This example is available on this page itself: look at the right hand pane of this page.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you very much.